# How to enable the pallet option in Jodit toolbar

Tags: jodit

I am currently using the Jodit editor and have enabled the "brush" button as follows:

```
 data() {
        return {
            editor: null,
            buttons: [
                "bold",
                "strikethrough",
                "underline",
                "italic",
                "|",
                "ul",
                "ol",
                "|",
                // "outdent",
                // "indent",
                "|",
                // "fontsize",
                "brush",
                "|",
                "link",
                "align"
            ],
            overlay: null,
            container: null,
            toolbar: null,
        }
    },
```

When I use this button I only have the ability to use predefined colors. On the Jodit playground page https://xdsoft.net/jodit/play.html when I click the button I am given an option to use a Hex or RGB color I enter. I have searched the documentation but see no reference to adding this ability.

How do I enable the ability to set my own color?